# Multiple underline colors in one anchor

Tags: html, css

I would like to, within one anchor `</a>`, have two different underline colors. Like so:

```
<a href="somehref">
    <span>This text should underline RED on `a` hover</span>
    <span>This text should underline GREY on `a` hover</span>
</a>
```

I can add `text-decoration` to each span on hover but this causes each line to hover individually. I want it so that when I hover over anywhere in the `</a>` both spans underline with their font `color` inherited.

Is this possible?

Note: I'm aware of `text-decoration-color` but due to limit support I cannot use it.

Comment: If you're not limited to CSS, then take a look at http://letteringjs.com/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some thing like this? You can use the anchor's `:hover` CSS pseudo class to style it's child and descendant.

Here is an reference to CSS [child](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/child/) and [descendant](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/d/descendant/) selectors.

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a span:first-child {
  color: red;
}
a span:last-child {
  color: grey;
}
a:hover span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="somehref">
  <span>This text should underline RED on `a` hover</span>
  <span>This text should underline GREY on `a` hover</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Using this code and switching `border-bottom` with `text-decoration: underline` solved my question.

Comment: @Geraint I can't reproduce what you did (I assume I'm doing something wrong). Are you saying instead of `border-bottom: 1px solid red` you have `text-decoration: underline 1px solid red`?

Comment: Sorry no, should've been clearer, instead of `border-bottom: 1px solid red` I did `text-decoration: underline`, this then gives me the underline when the `<a>` is hovered over and by default gains the color that is applied to the span

Comment: @Geraint : I have updated the answer based on your comments. Brian J - Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this?

```
a:hover span {
   text-decoration: underline; }
```

`text-decoration: underline` will inherit the font color automatically, so if your spans are already with gray/red colors, all you need to do is make them underline upon hovering the `a`

Answer (score 5):

You can also try this. if there are so many `span` element

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover span:nth-child(1){
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
a:hover span:nth-child(2){
  border-bottom:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<a href="somehref">
    <span>This text should underline RED on `a` hover</span>
    <span>This text should underline GREY on `a` hover</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```css
a{
 text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover #span1{
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
a:hover #span2{
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<a href="somehref">
    <span id="span1">This text should underline RED on `a` hover</span><br/>
    <span id="span2">This text should underline GREY on `a` hover</span>
</a>
```

Comment: You should use class instead of ID.

Comment: @Forty : Both are different . I am not using same ID for two spans

Comment: OP is asking for `underline` and you answer `you can use border instead`???

Comment: And you should use classes instead of IDs. IDs are meant for unique elements, not elements that might be repeated.

Comment: @HappyCoding : He needs the color only for the underline .not for the text and this is a possible solution

Comment: @Forty Don't worry about id, you can also use `span:nth-child(1)` and `span:nth-child(2)`. No more class, no more id.

Comment: Then if he decides gray must come first, or use that span somewhere else (or dozens of other possibilities), he'll need to run around fixing nth:child positions.

Answer (score 4):

I've added this to inherit the color of the span, which is what you wanted, rather than using the `HEX` in the underline. **Note that this is SCSS.**

> CSS Color Module - 4.4. **currentColor color keyword**
>
> CSS1 and CSS2 defined the initial value of the border-color property
>   to be the value of the color property but did not define a
>   corresponding keyword. This omission was recognized by SVG, and thus
>   SVG 1.0 introduced the currentColor value for the fill, stroke,
>   stop-color, flood-color, and lighting-color properties.
>
> CSS3 extends the color value to include the **currentColor** keyword to
>   allow its use with all properties that accept a  value. This
>   simplifies the definition of those properties in CSS3.

**Fiddle for you**

https://jsfiddle.net/4f0mL136/3/

```
<a href="somehref">
  <span>This text should underline RED on `a` hover</span>
  <span>This text should underline GREY on `a` hover</span>
</a>

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

span:last-child {
  color: black;
}

span:first-child {
  color: red;
}

a:hover {
  span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
  }
}

span {  // display purposes
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: border-bottom .2s ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

there are a few ways to do it
the best way is to create a class(in CSS) and set the color there
the second way is to insert the CSS in the html code
like here

```css
.tool1:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
.tool2:hover {
    background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
    </style>
     
    <body style="text-align:center;">

        <p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

        <a href="somehref">
            <span class='tool1'>This text should underline RED on `a` hover</span>
            <span class='tool2'>This text should underline GREY on `a` hover</span>
        </a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to meet the requirements. This highlights instead of setting text color, and it also only does one half of the anchor tag at a time, instead of both sides at once.