# How to use different colors in the same HTML link?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use different colors in the same HTML link. It seems to work at first, but when I hover over the link with the mouse, the underline is drawn with only a single color.

I'm using this HTML as CSS:

```css
body {
  background: #E7CEAF;
}

a {
  color: white;
  background: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: powderblue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.tag {
  font-style: italic;
  color: yellow;
}

a:hover .tag {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  /* doesn't work */
}
```

```html
This is some text: <a href="https://www.example.com"><span class="tag">[this is a tag] </span>This is a link, the tag being part of the link</a>
```

You can play with it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nj1y24L6).

As you can see there, the underline is blue, even under the yellow words. **How can I style the hovering links to display a yellow underline (or even no line) under the yellow part?**

Comment: See also [Multiple underline colors in one anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38481240/215552)

Comment: Or you can use [text-decoration-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color) for your span

Comment: @Sfili_81 please, don't forget to follow your advice with browser support stats in case it's [not supported but all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/text-decoration) out of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code part for `a:hover .tag` works fine and is rendered correctly, but there is an underline on the link on its own. So you need to remove the underline on the link and add it only to part with text.

```css
body {
  background: #E7CEAF;
}

a {
  color: white;
  background: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: powderblue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tag {
  font-style: italic;
  color: yellow;
}

a:hover .tag {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover .text {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
This is some text: <a href="https://www.example.com">
<span class="tag">[this is a tag] </span>
<span class="text">This is a link, the tag being part of the link</span></a>
```